# Redux thunk async action cannot access first parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I  have an action that currently works fine using `.then` but when I try and convert it to `async ... await` it suddenly can't access the first parameter of the function. The second parameter still works fine though.

Current function that works fine:

```
export const signInUser = (email, password) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('signed in')
        const { uid, email } = firebase.auth().currentUser
        dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', uid, email })
        return dispatch(fetchAllData())
      })
      .catch(error => {
        throw (error)
      })
  }
};
```

New function that doesn't work because 'email' is undefined.

```
export const signInUser = (email, password) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    console.log('testing')
    console.log(password)
    console.log('testing', email, password)
    await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    console.log('signed in')
    const { uid, email } = firebase.auth().currentUser
    dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', uid, email })
    return dispatch(fetchAllData())
  }
};
```

The first console log of `console.log('testing')` works fine and outputs the string 'testing'. The second console log of `console.log(password)` also works fine and prints the inputted password. But the third console log `console.log('testing', email, password)` doesn't get shown at all.

This is how the function is called:

Parent component passes it to child component:
`submit={(email, password) => dispatch(signInUser(email, password))}`

Child component calls it:

```
  const submitForm = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (validForm) {
      setLoading(true)
      submit(email, password)
        .catch(err => {
          setLoading(false)
          console.log('catch:', err.code)
          setError(err.code)
        })
    }
  }
```

The output I am receiving is `catch: undefined`.

Also, if I change the function to this:

```
export const signInUser = (email, password) => {
  const userEmail = email
  return async (dispatch) => {
    console.log('testing')
    console.log(password)
    console.log('testing', userEmail, password)
    await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, password)
    console.log('signed in')
    const { uid, email } = firebase.auth().currentUser
    dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', uid, email })
    return dispatch(fetchAllData())
  }
};
```

Then it works fine. But I don't know why I would need to change it like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the reason it wasn't working was because on the next line I was declaring email like this `const { uid, email } = firebase.auth().currentUser`
 which was overriding the function parameter of `email` and therefore giving me the error that i was using `email` before it was declared.